# SQL - Use DATEADD in GROUP BY (?)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Im working on a query that is meant to retrive sales by hour, which it does. However, in the used database table all the timestamps are `UTC +1`, also for sales made in a country with `UTC +2`.

So what I'm trying to achive is a result that can be used by local business units (a parameter is set depending on who is looking at a report will determine the which country/store to display). So when it's sales in a `UTC +2` country the datestamp needs to be modified with +1. 
I'm thinking this can be done in the group by, perhaps by using a `DATEADD` together with a condition that checks the county name. For example, when the country is 'Greece' (column exists in the database), use a `DATEADD` to add 1 hour to the timestamp.
Is this a possible solution and if so, how is it done?

This is the `GROUP BY` im using at the moment:

```
SELECT
DATEPART(hour, sales.OrderDate) AS Hour,
SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT(sales.OrderDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = Cast(GETDATE() AS date) THEN sales.SALES * (1 + sales.vv / 100) END) AS SALES, 
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FORMAT(sales.OrderDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = Cast(GETDATE() AS date) THEN sales.OID END) ) AS CUSTOMERS,
MAX(CASE WHEN FORMAT(sv.Date_Time, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = Cast(GETDATE() AS date) THEN sv.CC END) AS VISITORS

FROM
[DW].[Tot_Sales] AS sales
LEFT JOIN [DW].[SV_24M] AS sv ON dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, sales.[OrderDate]), 0) = dateadd(HOUR, 0, sv.Date_Time)
AND sales.SID = sv.SID

WHERE 
sales.SID = @Store 
AND FORMAT(sales.OrderDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') > DATEADD(year, - 1, Cast(GETDATE() AS date))

GROUP BY 
sales.SID, 
DATEPART(hour, sales.OrderDate)

ORDER BY 
DATEPART(hour, sales.OrderDate)
```

It is in the columns `SALES` and `CUSTOMERS` this needs to be applied, and they are from the table named `sales`. This is how the result looks:

[Resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2GFB.png)

The issue is that the sales and customers occuring at hour 9 actually occured hour 10 in `UCT +2`. Visitors data arrives in local time (`UCT +2` in this case), and therefore it's a mismatch between Visitors and Customers.

Sample data set:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzjm9.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You can use the following formula to localize the datetime: DATEDIFF(hh, getutcdate(), getdate()) -1. Subtract 1, because all date are in UTC+1. You should create a simple function that adapt the datetime and use it for all the sales.OrderDate values

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We are using a similar solution to get the dates to UTC+1 in the DW, they are unix time-format in local time from source. This query is for a ad-hoc report, so don't want to change anything in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the countries then you could make use of AT TIME ZONE in the query to set the appropriate local time.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks! Would probably be a more sophisticated way than use DATEADD for a certain country. However, my problem is more related to how to get DATEADD (or AT TIME ZONE) into the query the best way. If it can be placed in GROUP BY etc.